# Using Chef Solo and Vagrant how do I make the VM host ssh keys available to specific user?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo

Basically I want to access my github repos from a specific user.

Comment: only works for the vagrant user, or is there a way to get it working for other users

Comment: I am using a file provisioner which copies the key file from my host into the machine. If you want to do this from within chef, you can mount ~/.ssh from your host somewhere on your guest and then access this from chef.